# Get response from respond_with request rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Given this user action:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html, :js  

    def update
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        # do stuff...
        respond_with(@user)
    end
    #other functions
end
```

How do I print the response in my `app/views/users/update.js.erb` file?

I can access the @user variable in there, but how do I get the "status" or whether or not it was successful?

My current `app/views/users/update.js.erb` file looks like this:

```
console.log("update?");
console.log("<%=@user %>");
```

which prints:

```
udate?
#&lt;User:0x639a470&gt;
```

in the console.

Basically, I want to know if it was successful before trying to do things with @user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
console.log("<%=@user.to_json%>");
```

#### Update

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  # do stuff...

  if @user.save
    # user update was successful
    respond_with(@user)
  else
    flash[:error] = "User Update Failed"
    render :action => "some_action"
  end
end
```

Comment: That gives me `NoMethodError - undefined method `gsub' for #<User:0x6e0b680>:`

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: IN your controller's `do stuff` are you using any `gsub `?

Comment: I am not. It works if I don't call escape_javascript on it. Is there a way to grab the ajax's response from this side of things?

Comment: can you try? `console.log("<%=@user.to_json %>");`

Comment: Or, `console.log("<%=@user.inspect%>");`

Comment: That does exactly what you think, but how do I check if my update was successful? That just returns the user at it is, I need to display a message if the update was successful or not.

Comment: You can do that in your controller. When you can successfully save the user, then you do: `respond_with(@user)`

Comment: So if successful respond with '@user', else respond with @error or something?

Comment: yes, exactly. That way, in your js.erb file, if you get the user object, which means your update was successful. And, if your update was unsuccessful, you don't have anything to send to the js file. You just show the error message from the controller using a flash message or something like that.